# CameraX Android jetpack ROI

Tags: android, android-camera, android-jetpack

How to implement region of interest in cameraX?
In cameraX the particular region should scanned for barcode and text recognition.

Answer (score 2):

Overall the flow you would need is this:

1. Implement CameraX with ImageAnalysis use case.
2. In ImageAnalysis, in images, detect the bounding boxes of barcodes with a ML model or an algorithm of your choice.
3. Crop the region from the image and send it to your preferred barcode scan library for a result.(Image could be converted to a bitmap and apply cropping on it)
4. Bonus: If you want, you can pass all image to MLKit and it will return you the barcode string as well as bounding box of the barcodes. [Here](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android) is a guide for this.